# Get Python turtle window to display graphics and remain open

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In this code I can't see why it isn't printing a hexagon 24 times.  I tell it to make a 6 sided shape with 60 degrees between lines ( a hexagon) and tell it do turn 15 degrees each time.  This ends up being a even 24 for the picture I'm trying to draw.

```
import turtle

Hex_Count = 0

x = turtle.Turtle()
x.speed(.25)
def Hexagon():
    for i in range(24):
        for i in range(6):
            x.forward(100)
            x.left(60)
        Hex_Count = Hex_Count + 1
        x.left(15)
        print(Hex_Count)
Hexagon
```

But, for some reason, when I run this code the turtle screen pops up for about a half second then closes. How do I get it to perform in the way I want it to?

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors that I corrected for you; I added the explanation in the comments:

```
import turtle

hexagons_count = 0

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()       # x is not a good name for a Turtle object
# my_turtle.speed(.25)            # see @cdlane comment reported in a note under.

def draw_hexagon():               # use explicit names respecting python conventions (no camel case)
    global hexagons_count         # need global to modify the variable in the function scope
    for idx in range(24):         # use different dummy variable names in your loops 
        for jdx in range(6):      # use different dummy variable names in your loops
            my_turtle.forward(100)
            my_turtle.left(60)
        hexagons_count += 1
        my_turtle.left(15)
        print(hexagons_count)

draw_hexagon()             # need parenthesis to call the function

turtle.exitonclick()       # this to exit cleanly
```

[image]

> **Note:** I know you simply copied it from the OP but my_turtle.speed(.25)
>   doesn't make sense as the argument should be an int from 0 to 10 or a
>   string like 'slow', 'fastest', etc. I especially don't understand why
>   beginners with turtle code that isn't working call turtle.speed() at
>   all -- it seems to me a function to be tweaked after everything is
>   working. @cdlane

Comment: I know you simply copied it from the OP but `my_turtle.speed(.25)` doesn't make sense as the argument should be an int from 0 to 10 or a string like `'slow'`, `'fastest'`, etc.  I especially don't understand why beginners with turtle code that isn't working call `turtle.speed()` at all -- it seems to me a function to be tweaked after everything is working.

Comment: haha, I did not know that, thank you fro this comment, i learned something. I have added your comment as a note in my answer, and commented out the speed in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your program. One is that it will when after running through the program, closing the window it created. You can add `turtle.exitonclick()` to the end of your script which tells python to wait for a click in the graphics window, after which it will exit.

The second problem is that you don't call the `Hexagon` function because you're missing the parentheses. Even if a function takes no arguments, you still need to call it like:

```
Hexagon()
```

The final problem is that you need to define `Hex_Count` before you try to increment it. `Hex_Count + 1` will thrown an error if `Hex_Count` wasn't already assigned to. You can fix this by putting

```
Hex_Count = 0
```

before your for loop in `Hexagon`.

Comment: Rather than add `input()` at the end, the convention with turtle is to make the last statement a call to one of: `mainloop()`, `done()` or `exitonclick()` to turn control over to the Tk event handler. Except when running under IDLE (see the turtle documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

You have some reference issue, you just need to put the variable hex_count where it needs to be so you don't have error accessing it.

```
import turtle

x = turtle.Turtle()
x.speed(.25)
def Hexagon():
    Hex_Count = 0
    for i in range(24):
        for i in range(6):
            x.forward(100)
            x.left(60)
        Hex_Count += 1
        x.left(15)
    print(Hex_Count)
Hexagon()
```

prints `24`

Answer (score 0):

An approach different in a lot of the details but primarily in its use of `circle()` to more rapidly draw the hexagons:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen  # force object-oriented turtle

hex_count = 0  # global to count all hexagons drawn by all routines

def hexagons(turtle):
    global hex_count  # needed as this function *changes* hex_count

    for _ in range(24):  # don't need explicit iteration variable
        turtle.circle(100, steps=6)  # use circle() to draw hexagons
        turtle.left(15)  # 24 hexagons offset by 15 degrees = 360
        hex_count += 1  # increment global hexagon count
        print(hex_count)

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)  # keep turtle out of the drawing
yertle.speed('fastest')  # ask turtle to draw as fast as it can

hexagons(yertle)

screen.exitonclick()  # allow dismiss of window by clicking on it
```